# grid views values become null in the printing function

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am trying to print a grid view.

I got `null exception` on this line

```
e.Graphics.DrawString
          (
            this.GridView
                .Rows[rowCounter]
                .Cells[0]
                .Value
                .ToString(), 
            valueFont, 
            Brushes.Black, 
            realwidth, 
            realheight
          );
```

which exist in this function `printDocument1_PrintPage`

So I tried to replace the `this.GridView.Rows[rowCounter].Cells[0].Value.ToString()` with string like `Hello`, the exception goes and the code works.

Then, I make a button and inside that button I did this:

```
int r = 0;
while (r < GridView.Rows.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GridView.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value);
    r++;
}
return;
```

and that code works fine with no exception

so why when accessing the grid view from the printing function i got null exception and when accessing it from another function it works fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lajos Arpad has nailed the reason why the values 'sometimes' contain a null and sometimes seemingly not..:

They always do but `Console.Write()` quietly ignores null values so your tests were misleading.

The reason why they always contain null values in the last row is the `DataGridview` property `AllowUserToAddRows` which is by default true. The result is that one empty Row is inserted at the end, so that the user can enter data and also add more rows.

If this is not wanted you must turn off `AllowUserToAddRows`before you fill the DGV.

To make the application more robust you may want to include checks for null at some point; here the main thing to consider is how to treat them: Ignore them like the Console, tell the user and let him/her continue or not or log the problem to an IT person..?

Answer (score 2):

You did not write equivalent code. You have

```
e.Graphics.DrawString
          (
            this.GridView
                .Rows[rowCounter]
                .Cells[0]
                .Value
                .ToString(), 
            valueFont, 
            Brushes.Black, 
            realwidth, 
            realheight
          );
```

as your first try and you have

```
int r = 0;
while (r < GridView.Rows.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GridView.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value);
    r++;
}
return;
```

as your second try. In the first try you also called `ToString` and in the second try you just referenced the value. I guess you have `null` as `Value` for at least a row for the given cell and `null` does not have a method called `ToString`. That should have been the problem. You can easily test whether I am right or wrong with the following code:

```
int r = 0;
while (r < GridView.Rows.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine(GridView.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    r++;
}
return;
```

Comment: yes when I tried your solution with `tostring` i got null exception on the r = 234. do you suggest removing the .tostring ? or validating the value before calling .tostring?

Comment: I noticed that the problem always appear in the last row, for example if there are 1000 row, the row 999 becomes null, why please? is it by default there is a one row in the grid view?

Comment: I did not use C# for a looong time, so I do not know how GridView is populated, however, I guess the null appears when you populate the GridView, I would check that code if I were you, as you might have one more step in the cycle than needed.

Comment: You don't show us how the DGV gets filled. Try to set `AllowUserToAddRows = false` so the extra empty row doesn't get created, where the user would enter data..!

Comment: @TaW yes that works perfectly, please write an answer to accept it

Comment: @LajosArpad +1 for your appreciated effort

Answer (score 0):

Null object could not have a method like `.ToString()`. if the value in `GridView.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value` is null then it cannot be converted into string using `.ToString()` method. You need to place a condition here.

```
if (GridView.Rows[r].Cells[0].Value != null)
    e.Graphics.DrawString
          (
            this.GridView
                .Rows[rowCounter]
                .Cells[0]
                .Value
                .ToString(), 
            valueFont, 
            Brushes.Black, 
            realwidth, 
            realheight
          );
```

Make sure the `AllowUserToAddRow` property is false. if it is true then last row(New Row) will always return null value. And it could be the reason of this exception. Or you can avoid the last row to print `for (int i=0; i< grid.Rows.Count-2;i++)`. But, i don't think that it is the good way. You just need to place if condition to check value is null or not.